# Clear application cache from list

Tags: java, android, caching, android-listview, android-alertdialog

I need to delete the cache of an application i click in my listview that shows all application installed in the phone.. I found this code:

```
public void clearApplicationData() {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                    Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null &amp;amp;&amp;amp; dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }
```

but this one delete cache of current application i use and not which i have choosen. I don't know if i'm clear.. What i want is create a dialog that if you click in yes button clear the cache of that application.. So far i wrote this:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:" + " "+app.packageName);
                        File file =new File("com.dd.application");
                        long size=file.length()/1024;
                        File cache = getCacheDir();
                        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
                        if (appDir.exists()) {
                            String[] children = appDir.list();
                            for (String s : children) {
                                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cache deleted of" + " " +packageUri+ size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + packageUri + " DELETED *******************");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Actually when i click yes, it shows me the right package name but doesn't clear the cache.. Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot clear the application cache of any application other than your own. This would be a serious security flaw. The `getCacheDir()` method will only return a reference to only your app's cache directory.

Comment: Ah, so do you think is an unusless feature?

Comment: It doesn't matter what I think. It is not allowed as part of the OS security model. You might find a way to do this in rooted devices but not the regular ones.

Comment: and force stop the application is allowed?

Comment: no it's not. It's only allowed for your own application unless the device is rooted and your app has root privileges.